# why vitetest not work? getWebGLRenderingContext?

Tags: vite, vitest

why its not work ?

```
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Failed Tests 4 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
 FAIL  src/game/managers/Ressources/Ressources.m.test.ts > RessourcesManager > should initialize correctly       
 FAIL  src/game/managers/Ressources/Ressources.m.test.ts > RessourcesManager > should load scene data
 FAIL  src/game/managers/Ressources/Ressources.m.test.ts > RessourcesManager > should find textures by category  
 FAIL  src/game/managers/Ressources/Ressources.m.test.ts > RessourcesManager > should get texture from database  
ReferenceError: WebGLRenderingContext is not defined
 ❯ Object.getWebGLRenderingContext node_modules/@pixi/settings/src/adapter.ts:38:25
 ❯ new ScissorSystem node_modules/@pixi/core/src/mask/ScissorSystem.ts:41:6
 ❯ Renderer.addSystem node_modules/@pixi/core/dist/esm/core.mjs:9349:22
 ❯ new Renderer node_modules/@pixi/core/src/Renderer.ts:314:9
 ❯ src/game/managers/Ressources/Ressources.m.test.ts:10:20
      8| 
      9|  beforeEach( () => {
     10|   const renderer = new Renderer();
       |                    ^
     11|   ressourcesManager = new RessourcesManager( renderer ); // Pass the required argument to the construct…     12|  });
```

[image]

my vite config:

```
    /// <reference types="vitest" />
import path from 'path';

// import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

// import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/

export default defineConfig({
    logLevel: 'error',
    css:{
        devSourcemap: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        tsconfigPaths(),

        // react({
        //  babel: {
        //      parserOpts: {
        //          plugins: ['decorators-legacy'],
        //      },
        //  },
        // })

        // react({
        //  fastRefresh: true,
        //  babel: {
        //      parserOpts: {
        //          plugins: ['decorators-legacy', 'classProperties']
        //      }
        //  }
        // })
    ],

    ssr: {
        noExternal:true, //performance ?
        // noExternal: /^(?!.*\/vitest\/).*$/,
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,

        // setupFiles: ['./vitest.setup.ts'],
        environment: 'jsdom',

        // environment: 'happy-dom',
        server: {
            deps: {
                inline:[/^(?!.*vitest).*$/],

            }
        },

        deps:{
            optimizer: {
                web: {
                    include: ['vitest-canvas-mock'],
                },
            },
        }

    },

    // test: {
    //  environment: 'jsdom',
    //  globals: true,

    // },
    build: {
        target: 'esnext',
        sourcemap: true,
        minify: false,
        cssMinify: false,

    },

    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            keepNames: true,
        },
    },
    server: {

        watch: {
            ignored: [
                path.resolve( __dirname, 'src/game/actionscripts/index.ts' ),

                // ignore all files in the actionscripts
                // path.resolve( __dirname, 'src/game/actionscripts/**/*' ),
            ]
        }
    },
    experimental:{

    },
    resolve: {
        // alias: {
        //  '@ECS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/libraries/ECS' ),
        //  '@UTILS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/utils' ),
        //  '@TYPES': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/types' ),

        //  // game domain
        //  '@GAME': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game' ),
        //  '@GAME-CORE': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/core' ),
        //  '@GAME-COMMANDS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/commands' ),

        //  // '@GAME-ENUMS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/core/enum' ),
        //  // '@GAME-CONSTS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/core/const' ),
        //  // '@GAME-DB': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/core/db' ),

        //  // '@GAME-CORE': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/core' ),
        //  '@GAME-MODULES': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/modules' ),
        //  '@GAME-ACTIONSCRIPTS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/actionscripts' ),
        //  '@GAME-ENTITIES': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/ecs/entities' ),
        //  '@GAME-COMPONENTS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/ecs/components' ),
        //  '@GAME-SYSTEMS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/ecs/systems' ),
        //  '@GAME-PACKAGE': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/game/packages' ),

        //  // editor domain
        //  '@EDITOR': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor' ),
        //  '@EDITOR-CORE': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor/core' ),
        //  '@EDITOR-MODULES': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor/modules' ),
        //  '@EDITOR-ACTIONSCRIPTS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor/actionscripts' ),
        //  '@EDITOR-JSX': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor/jsx' ),
        //  '@EDITOR-HOOK': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor/jsx/hooks/' ),
        //  '@EDITOR-COMPOSITE': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor/jsx/composite/' ),
        //  '@EDITOR-ENTITIES': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor/entities' ),
        //  '@EDITOR-COMPONENTS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor/components' ),
        //  '@EDITOR-SYSTEMS': path.resolve( __dirname, './src/editor/systems' ),
        // },
    },
});
```

**test minimal example:**

```js
import { RessourcesManager } from './Ressources.m';
import { Renderer } from 'pixi.js'; // this import webgl or canvas fallback

describe( 'RessourcesManager', () => {
    let ressourcesManager: RessourcesManager;

    beforeEach( () => {
        const renderer = new Renderer({ width: 800, height: 600 });
        ressourcesManager = new RessourcesManager( renderer );
    });

    describe( 'getTexture', () => {
        it( 'should have renderer', () => {
            expect( ressourcesManager['renderer']).toBeDefined( );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hi thanks for your time, i update the minimal reproduction code, the dependancy seem crash it pixijs:
https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/blob/abecc358a0ce73fc301611ca5c2eecfd3dc7c38f/packages/settings/src/adapter.ts#L44C25-L44C25